# Extracting in PHP, Long and Lat from an address via API

Tags: php, function, api

I still try to extract Long and Lat from an address through the data.gouv API.
I've got that code:

```
function extractLatLngFromAdd($address) {
$address = "paris";         
    $geodata = json_decode ('https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q='. $address ); 

    // extract latitude and longitude
    $result['latitude']  = $geodata->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[1];
    $result['longitude'] = $geodata->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[0];

return $result;
}
 
print_r(extractLatLngFromAdd($address));
```

Then, with this function, I hope extracting the array below:

```
$lab = array(
    "repartition" => array(
        array( 
            "latLng" => array( extractLatLngFromAdd('Paris') ),
            "name" => "Paris",
            "code" => "FR-75"
        ),
        array( 
            "latLng" => array( extractLatLngFromAdd('grenoble') ),
            "name" => "Grenoble",
            "code" => "FR-38"
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($lab);
```

And the result is:

```
Array ( [latitude] => [longitude] => ) {"repartition":[{"latLng":[{"latitude":null,"longitude":null}],"name":"Paris","code":"FR-75"},{"latLng":[{"latitude":null,"longitude":null}],"name":"Grenoble","code":"FR-38"}]}
```

The latLng should be:

```
$lab = array(
        "repartition" => array(
            array( 
                "latLng" => array( 2.347, 48.859 ),
                "name" => "Paris",
                "code" => "FR-75"
            ),
            array( 
                "latLng" => array( 5.7243, 45.182081 ),
                "name" => "Grenoble",
                "code" => "FR-38"
            )
        )
    );
```

like that:

```
{"repartition":[{"latLng":[2.347,48.859],"name":"Paris","code":"FR-75"}
```

How to retrieve latitude and longitude from this function and how could I retrieve it in the $lab arrays?..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call the external API with `file_get_contents()` (`json_decode()` can't do that alone).
And in your $lab declaration, you don't need to put result in extra array, the result is already an array.

```
<?php

function extractLatLngFromAdd($address)
{
    $geodata = file_get_contents('https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=' . $address);
    $geodata = json_decode($geodata);

    // extract latitude and longitude
    $result['latitude']  = $geodata->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[1];
    $result['longitude'] = $geodata->features[0]->geometry->coordinates[0];

    return $result;
}

$lab = array(
    "repartition" => array(
        array(
            "latLng" => extractLatLngFromAdd('Paris'),
            "name" => "Paris",
            "code" => "FR-75"
        ),
        array(
            "latLng" => extractLatLngFromAdd('grenoble'),
            "name" => "Grenoble",
            "code" => "FR-38"
        )
    )
);

print_r($lab);
```

Gives :

```
Array
(
    [repartition] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [latLng] => Array
                        (
                            [latitude] => 48.859
                            [longitude] => 2.347
                        )
                    [name] => Paris
                    [code] => FR-75
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [latLng] => Array
                        (
                            [latitude] => 45.182081
                            [longitude] => 5.7243
                        )
                    [name] => Grenoble
                    [code] => FR-38
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Just as a note `file_get_contents` requires that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled which can be enable at runtime with `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);`. An alternative if you can't use `file_get_contents` is using `curl`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Because I had a warning err: "Warning: file_get_contents(https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=Paris): failed to open stream: Connection timed out"... I couldn't solve it. So thanks to your answer and comment, I have had to move from my free server to my ovh server to get this code working. Thanks a lot. BTW, i would be interested to do it with curl. Good point!